# Android: После внесения изменений в проект пропадает R.java

Tags: android, xml

Делаю учебный проект. Столкнулся с мистикой:

после прописывания идентификатора для View и старта app в эмуляторе, в проекте необъяснимым образом пропадает R.java.

Подробнее:

Задаем идентификаторы:

```
  <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@color/color_accent">

                        <TextView

                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/user_profile.placeholder.image"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                            android:layout_above="@id/photo_placeholder"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/photo_placeholder"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/placeholder_photo_size_90"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/placeholder_photo_size_90"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@drawable/add_a_photo_48px"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_large_56"/>


                    </RelativeLayout>
```

Запускаем приложение в эмуляторе, чтобы посмотреть, как выглядят вьюшки.

После запуска приложения получаем ошибку:

Error:(58, 51) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/photo_placeholder').

Ошибка связана с тем, что из проекта начисто пропали все R.java.

Запуск app с более ранними изменениями ни к чему подобному не приводил.

Я в аху... некотором замешательстве.

Не надеясь на Git, делал локальные бэкапы проекта после каждого изменения, при котором проект оставался работоспособным. Это и позволило точно определить момент исчезновения R.java.

R.java пропадают именно в момент запуска app.

Что это может быть?

Работа встала, я не понимаю, что происходит.

Вот R.java, найденные поиском в проекте до мистических изменений:

[image: До изменений]

После все эти файлы отсутствуют, сборка крашится.

Техническая информация:

Проект: https://github.com/miller7777777/DevIntensive
ветка Hometask_3
смотреть файл DevIntensive\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml

Windows 10x64
Android Studio 2.1.2

Винт здоровый, прошелся chkdsk, проблем нет. Вирусов нет.

Clean project/Rebuild Project тоже не помогают.

Что это может быть?

Comment: Да, вы правы. Перенес "+" в первое упоминаниеID photo_placeholder - все заработало. Благодарю! Код целиком выкладывать не буду, там большая простыня, выложу только проблемный кусок.

Answer (score 2):

Класс `R` автогенрируется при каждой компиляции, но он не создается, если в разметке есть ошибки. Здесь нет никакой мистики - просто компилятор не может преобразовать XML в код и собрать проект, соответственно генерировать `R` ему не из чего.

Перенесите "плюсик" после комерческого AT (@+id) в первое упоминание ID `photo_placeholder` в вашей разметке (В атрибут `android:layout_above` виджета `TextView` в вашем случае):

```
 <TextView
    ...
    android:layout_above="@+id/photo_placeholder"/>
```

А в остальных упоминаниях этого ID "плюсик" уберите (в частности в атрибуте `android:id` виджета `ImageView`).

Из ошибки вполне очевидно следует, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к ресурсу по имени, которого еще нет/ Имя связывается с ресурсом этим самым "плюсиком" и первое упоминание имени в разметке должно быть с "плюсиком" - этот "плюсик" указывает, что необходимо добавить имя виджету для последующего обращения к нему.